# How to configure DNS (and/or loadbalancing) for Docker Swarm Manager

Tags: docker, dns, consul, docker-swarm

**Scenario:**

I'm building and configuring one Docker Swarm cluster. My idea is to deploy 2 sets of 3 virtual machines in 2 separated Hosts (`HostA` and `HostB`), using Consul as discovery backend:

`HostA`: `manager0`, `node0`, `node1`

`HostB`: `manager1`, `node2`, `node3`

By this way, I get the desired redundancy in both the Swarm managers and nodes. However, **my current situation is in an earlier and much simpler stage**: I've just spun a single Docker Swarm manager as follow:

```
docker \
  run -d \
  -p 3376:3376 \
  swarm manage \
  -H :3376 --advertise manager0:3376 \
  --replication consul://consul0:8500/
```

(Note: The command above has been adapted for this question as some irrelevant arguments such as TLS verification have been cleared.)

This first seed of the Swarm cluster works as expected:

```
docker -H tcp://manager0:3376 version
Client:
Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      swarm/1.2.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   eaa53c7
 Built:        Fri May 27 17:25:03 UTC 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**Question:**

Let's say I successfully address the initial plan and I add a second manager, the secondary. As far as I can see, Consul maintain the information about the Swarm cluster, it knows who is the primary and the secondary, it performs healthchecks and so forth.

Now, I wear my deployer hat. I want to connect my Docker client to the Swarm cluster in order to deploy, for instance, my nginx-based services. I don't want to manually connect to either `manager0` or `manager1` depending on which one is the primary in each case, I'd like to use a single endpoint to the whole cluster. So:

**How do I use Consul DNS resolution to point to the correct Swarm manager using a single endpoint?** For example:

```
docker -H tcp://swarm.cluster.example.com:3376 version
```

instead of either:

```
docker -H tcp://manager0:3376 version
```

or

```
docker -H tcp://manager1:3376 version
```

Comment: Tip: By adding the second host, you're actually reducing fault tolerance. That's because the distributed configuration tools require a quorum, or over 50% of the nodes to be available. So if one host goes down, the other no longer has quorum to operate. You need at least 3 hosts to support one host going down.

Comment: If you're developing a new swarm now, I'd go the 1.12 route, the new `docker swarm` and `docker service` commands remove a lot of the challenges you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Hi @BMitch, thanks for your suggestion about 1.12 route. I'll consider this for the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `HostA` and `HostB` should use Consul as a DNS Server. To do that, you need change default DNS Server Port of Consul to 53. After that, you change Domain Name Server of Hosts (file /etc/resolv.conf).

See the link https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html

> The DNS query system makes use of health check information to prevent
>   routing to unhealthy nodes. When a service query is made, any services
>   failing their health check or failing a node system check will be
>   omitted from the results. To allow for simple load balancing, the set
>   of nodes returned is also randomized each time. These mechanisms make
>   it easy to use DNS along with application-level retries as the
>   foundation for an auto-healing service oriented architecture.

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen - I'm going to try this. I'm very new at Consul and its documentation assumes some fundamental knowledge that I don't control yet.